# Ag grid resetting filters

Tags: angular, filter, ag-grid

I have tried to use ag grid for angular 2 and faced with the following behavior:

When I'm trying to type anything in column filter, grid is going to reload and reset filter as well. It happens not only if I type something for filtration but even if I'm trying to change type of the filter.

Anybody had similar issue?

Comment: Do you have any code you can share with us to illustrate the problem? Its also worth noting that the latest version of ag-grid-ng2 supports filters as ng2 components - might be worth investigating that

Comment: @SeanLandsman
Did you ever figure out what is going on? I am having the same problem, as soon as I set the filter type, it goes to datasource.getRows to get the new rows, then all of the sudden the filter is reset back to nothing.

Comment: @Josh - if you can provide a plunker I'm happy to take a look and see if I can find the problem

Comment: @SeanLandsman Did you find any solution ? I am having same problem

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this issue by adding property :  newRowsAction: 'keep'

```
columnDefinition = {
    headerName: 'Athlete',
    field: 'athlete'
    // set the column to use text filter
    filter: 'text',
    // pass in additional parameters to the text filter
    filterParams: {apply: true, newRowsAction: 'keep'}
   }
```

From the ag-grid docs : https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/#gsc.tab=0

Comment: It works for me, but in examples provided by ag-grid filters don't clear by default. So something wrong is happening.